# ClassNotFoundException stores own copy of cause

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, standard-library

I have Oracle's Java implementation (1.6.0_37) and I'm interested in `ClassNotFoundException` source code. If you look in it you will see that this class stores it's own copy of cause:

```
private Throwable ex;
```

I just don't see any point in it - it is totally similar to the field declared in `Throwable` class.

Could anyone please explain me why does Java class library developers decided to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because nobody thought to remove it.

The `cause` was added to `Throwable` in [JDK 1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html); it wasn't present in [1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).

However, the [1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) version of `ClassNotFoundException` did have a cause, because this exception can happen when a static initializer fails (actually, due to any loading problem), and debugging without knowing the cause could be extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

May be they wanted to be backward compatible for exception objects serialized with the older Java versions.
Keeping the field seems simpler than maintaining custom writeObject/readObject methods.